# What would the phrase 'modern currents of thought' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am preparing for an exam in which one of the criteria to judge candidates is:

> Candidates are expected to have taken an intelligent interest not only in their special subjects of
>   academic study but also in the events which are happening around them both within and outside
>   their own State or Country as well as in modern currents of thought.

I get most parts of the paragraph but am not able to decipher *modern currents of thought*. What would it mean?

I hope the question is on-topic here. Thank you!

Comment: Think of it metaphorically: intellectual discourse has currents, or directions they flow.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more...would love to accept an informative answer. The phrase is specific about a quality of the 'currents of thought', and I am already confused with 'currents of thought'.

Comment: I will in the next hour. :)

Comment: It's a little weird, given that "currents of thought" is borderline archaic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sense, *currents of thought* would refer to the ideas currently popular in intellectual communities.

At first I wanted to think of this metaphorically. A *current* is a flow or rhythm; a *current of thought* is a tendency for thought to move a certain way in literate discourse. Fortunately Collins Dictionary has [a definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/current) of *current* that uses *current of thought* as an example.

> 4. A particular current is a particular feeling, idea, or quality that exists within a group of people.
>
> "Each party represents a distinct **current of thought**."

*Currents of thought* are similar to the *state of the art*, the current *paradigm*, or the prevailing theories of the day. These *currents* are often external to one's own subject area. Two examples from academic texts:

> [Some](https://books.google.com/books?id=HEcwBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA16&ots=nGQdXxRK4x&dq=%22modern%20currents%20of%20thought%22&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=%22modern%20currents%20of%20thought%22&f=false) psychologists, reflecting more **modern currents of thought**, disagreed with Wundt's version of psychology and proposed their own. (One set of ideas influenced psychologists to reconsider their assumptions.)
>
> [Keen](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modern_Judaism/bugTDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) to respond to **modern currents of thought**, (reconstructionism) also implemented gender equality far more quickly than other movements. (A religious reform movement responds to contemporary discourse on gender equality by implementing it.)

Basically, if I were to open up a periodical that has some kind of intellectual bent, like The Atlantic, what sort of ideas would be under discussion? If I met another generally educated person at a party, what ideas could I presume that person to be at least a little familiar with? The idea of multiple learning styles (visual, aural, kinaesthic) aiding learning, the idea of work-life balance being important to the modern worker, the idea that the Bechdel test is a useful measure of female characters' participation in films - those ideas could be part of the prevailing *currents of thought*.

Comment: (+1) for the examples and an insightful answer I will wait for others to contribute before accepting it. Thank you!